# How can I get the form group validation result in the template driven form?

Tags: angular

I refer the following web page for create a form group in a template-driven form:

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/formgroup-in-angular/

I have a template-driven form.
I embed a form group in this form.
How can I get the form group validation result?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-um4w17?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is my code.

Why the following code always returns true? even I empty all input form fields.

```
console.log(this.manualGroup.errors===null);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why the following code always returns true?

`manualGroup` is not able to have its own validation because it is not a `FormControl`. And `FormGroup` doesn't have errors of its children either. I guess you were expecting that.

If you want just to get validation of `FormGroup`, use `this.manualGroup.valid` instead.